# share svn and git repo's between windows and linux

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot, git, svn

I dual boot my machine (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04). If I were to assign a separate partition just to hold my software repositories, what's the best partition type to share the same git and svn repostory folders between both operating systems. Seems wasteful to have copies of the same repositories in their native partition types.

Answer (score 0):

This question is basically the same as "what filesystem do I format an external drive to so that it is accessible on both Windows and Linux?" And the answer to that is FAT32 as seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#OS_support).

Comment: Why not NTFS? That seems the more logical choice in most cases.

Comment: FAT32 is usually ready to go in both Windows and Linux. NTFS support may need to be added to your Linux installation. My opinion is that, on Linux, NTFS is slightly less bulletproof than FAT32. That said, NTFS is certainly a usable solution for your situation.